# More Efficient Way To Run A Find Function

Tags: batch-file

Currently this script pretty well, but its slow are crap, going through a couple thousand files takes nearly 3 hours. Anyone got any tips to make the script more efficient or work better?

The script is pretty strait forward, finds the patch, kb numbers, architecture,  etc then puts them in the correct file. Anything  it can't find a match for it moves to an "uncategorized" file where i can adjust the script to include that file.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
SET "Titlebar=Text File Generator"
TITLE %Titlebar%
SET "SystemType=Standard"
FOR /F %%A IN ('DIR /B /A:-D ^|findstr "csv"') DO DEL /F %%A
ECHO/ Generating Text Files. This may take up to 10 minutes...
ECHO Architecture,KB Number, File Path, Switch, ,Windows 2000,Windows XP,Server 2003,Windows Vista,Server 2008,Windows 7,Office 2000,Office 2003,Office 2007,Office 2010, ,KB Info URL>>Masterlist.csv
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%I IN ('DIR /S /B /A:-D') DO SET /A MaxCnt+=1
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%I IN ('DIR /S /B /A:-D') DO CALL:Generate "%%I" 2>Nul>Nul
EXIT /B

:Progress
SET /A Percent=100*%1/%2
SET Percent=!Percent!%%
TITLE %titlebar% %CurentCnt% Of %MaxCnt% (%ProgressFormat:!Percent!% Complete)
EXIT /B

:Generate
SET /A CurentCnt+=1
SETLOCAL
CALL:Progress %CurentCnt% %MaxCnt%
IF /I "%~x1" NEQ ".exe" (
    IF /I "%~x1" NEQ ".msu" (
        IF /I "%~x1" NEQ ".msi" (
            IF /I "%~x1" NEQ ".msp" (
                ECHO "%~1">>SkippedFiles.csv
                EXIT /B
            )
        )
    )
)
CALL:FindKB "%~n1"
FINDSTR /I "%KB%" "%~dp0\Script Dependencies\Superseded-patches.txt" >Nul && EXIT /B
CALL:PathFix "%~1"
CALL:FindArchitecture "%~n1"
CALL:FindMS
CALL:FindOS "%~n1"
CALL:CustomRules "%~x1"
CALL:SwitchFix "%~n1"
CALL:FinalCheck
CALL:Export
ENDLOCAL
GOTO:EOF

:Export
IF NOT DEFINED KB       ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%, ,%Windows2000%,%WindowsXP%,%Server2003%,%Vista%,%Server2008%,%Windows7%,%Office2000%,%Office2003%,%Office2007%,%Office2010%>>MasterList.csv
IF DEFINED KB           ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%, ,%Windows2000%,%WindowsXP%,%Server2003%,%Vista%,%Server2008%,%Windows7%,%Office2000%,%Office2003%,%Office2007%,%Office2010%, ,http://support.microsoft.com/kb/%KB:~2%>>MasterList.csv
IF DEFINED Windows2000  SET "Exported=1"    & ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-Windows2000.csv
IF DEFINED WindowsXP    SET "Exported=1"    & ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-WindowsXP.csv
IF DEFINED Server2003   SET "Exported=1"    & ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-Server2003.csv
IF DEFINED Vista        SET "Exported=1"    & ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-Vista.csv
IF DEFINED Windows7     SET "Exported=1"    & ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-Windows7.csv
IF DEFINED Server2008   SET "Exported=1"    & ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-Server2008.csv
IF DEFINED Office2000   SET "Exported=1"    & ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-Office2000.csv
IF DEFINED Office2003   SET "Exported=1"    & ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-Office2003.csv
IF DEFINED Office2007   SET "Exported=1"    & ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-Office2007.csv
IF DEFINED Office2010   SET "Exported=1"    & ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-Office2010.csv

IF DEFINED WinOS SET "Exported=1"
IF DEFINED WinOS ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-Windows2000.csv
IF DEFINED WinOS ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-WindowsXP.csv
IF DEFINED WinOS ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-Server2003.csv
IF DEFINED WinOS ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-Vista.csv
IF DEFINED WinOS ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-Windows7.csv
IF DEFINED WinOS ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-Server2008.csv
IF NOT DEFINED Exported ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>Uncategorized.csv
EXIT /B


:FindArchitecture
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "x64"                   &&  ( SET "Architecture=x64"                    & SET /A "Count+=1" )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "x86"                   &&  ( SET "Architecture=x86"                    & SET /A "Count+=1" )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "IA64"                  &&  ( SET "Architecture=ia64"                   & SET /A "Count+=1" )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "AMD64"                 &&  ( SET "Architecture=amd64"                  & SET /A "Count+=1" )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "x86x64"                &&  ( SET "Architecture=x86x64"                 & SET /A "Count-=1" )
IF "%Count%" GTR "1" ( SET "Architecture=Error" )
SET Count=0
EXIT /B

:FindOS
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "Windows2000"           &&  ( SET "Windows2000=1"                   & SET /A "Count+=1" )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "WindowsXP"             &&  ( SET "WindowsXP=1"                     & SET /A "Count+=1" )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "WindowsServer2003"     &&  ( SET "Server2003=1"                    & SET /A "Count+=1" )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "Windows5.1"            &&  ( SET "WindowsXP=1"                     & SET /A "Count+=1" )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "Windows5.2"            &&  ( SET "Server2003=1"                    & SET /A "Count+=1" )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "Windows6.0"            &&  ( SET "Vista=1"                         & SET /A "Count+=1" )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "Windows6.1"            &&  ( SET "Windows7=1" & SET "Server2008=1" & SET /A "Count+=1" )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "Windows7"              &&  ( SET "Windows7=1"                      & SET /A "Count+=1" )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "Vista"                 &&  ( SET "Vista=1"                         & SET /A "Count+=1" )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "Server2008"            &&  ( SET "Server2008=1"                    & SET /A "Count+=1" )
IF "%Count%" GTR "1" ( SET "OS=Error" )
SET Count=0
EXIT /B

:FindKB
set val="%~1"
ECHO !val!|findstr /irc:"KB[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" >nul && (
    set "val=!val:*KB=!"
    Set "KB=KB!val:~0,7!"
    EXIT /B
)

ECHO !val!|findstr /irc:"KB[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" >nul && (
    set "val=!val:*KB=!"
    Set "KB=KB!val:~0,6!"
    EXIT /B
)

ECHO !val!|findstr /irc:"KB[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" >nul && (
    set "val=!val:*KB=!"
    Set "KB=KB!val:~0,5!"
    EXIT /B
)
EXIT /B

:FindMS
FOR /F "Tokens=2 Delims=/" %%A IN ("%Path%") DO SET "MS=%%A"
EXIT /B

:PathFix
SET "Path_to_convert=%~1"
SET "Reference_path=%~dp0"
SET "FilePath=!Path_to_convert:*%Reference_path%=!"
GOTO:EOF

:SwitchFix
SET "Switch=/quite /norestart"
IF "%Office2003%"=="1" SET "Switch=/Q"
IF "%~1"==".msu" SET "Switch=/quiet /norestart"
EXIT /B

:CustomRules
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "972581"            &&  ( SET "KB=KB972581" )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "MS09-035"          &&  ( SET "WinOS=All" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "msxml4"            &&  ( SET "WinOS=All" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "NDP40"             &&  ( SET "WinOS=All" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "KB890830"          &&  ( SET "WinOS=All" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "NetFramework"      &&  ( SET "WinOS=ALL" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "msxml6"            &&  ( SET "Server2003=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "NDP20"             &&  ( SET "WindowsXP=1" & SET "Server2003=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "KB969878"          &&  ( SET "WindowsXP=1" & SET "Server2003=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "WYukon2005Setup"   &&  ( SET "Server2003=1" & SET "Server2008=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "KB952068"          &&  ( SET "Server2008=1" & SET "Server2003=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "KB954600"          &&  ( SET "Server2008=1" & SET "Server2003=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "KB924430"          &&  ( SET "Server2000=1" & SET "Server2003=1" & SET "Architecture=x86" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "messenger"         &&  ( SET "Server2000=1" & SET "Server2003=1" & SET "WindowsXP=1" & SET "Architecture=x86" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "msxml4"            &&  ( SET "WinOS=All" & SET "Architecture=x86x64" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "KB974882"          &&  ( SET "WinOS=All" & SET "Architecture=x86x64" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "vcredist"          &&  ( SET "WinOS=All" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "WindowsServer2003" &&  ( SET "Server2003=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "KB974945"          &&  ( SET "WinOS=All" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "WindowsMedia"      &&  ( SET "WinOS=All" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "Windows-2000-XP"   &&  ( SET "WindowsXP=1" & SET "Server2000=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "KB960089"          &&  ( SET "Server2008=1" & SET "Server2003=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "KB960083"          &&  ( SET "WinOS=All" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "KB2657424"         &&  ( SET "Server2008=1" & SET "Vista=1" & SET "Server2003=1" & SET "WindowsXP=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "KB2656370"         &&  ( SET "WindowsXP=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "KB2541015"         &&  ( SET "Office2003=1" & SET "Architecture=x86" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "NDP"               &&  ( SET "WinOS=All" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "vcredist"          &&  ( SET "WinOS=All" & SET "Switch=/q" & EXIT /B )

::------------------------------------------------------------------
::-- Office --------------------------------------------------------
::------------------------------------------------------------------
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "Officexp"          &&  ( SET "WindowsXP=1" & SET "Architecture=x86" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "office2000"        &&  ( SET "Office2000=1" & SET "Architecture=x86" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "Office2003"        &&  ( SET "Office2003=1" & SET "Architecture=x86" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "outlook2003"       &&  ( SET "Office2003=1" & SET "Architecture=x86" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "Project2003"       &&  ( SET "Office2003=1" & SET "Architecture=x86" & EXIT /B )

::------------------------------------------------------------------
::-- Office 2007 ---------------------------------------------------
::------------------------------------------------------------------
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "Office2007"        &&  ( SET "Office2007=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "publisher2007"     &&  ( SET "Office2007=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "access2007"        &&  ( SET "Office2007=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "outlook2007"       &&  ( SET "Office2007=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "excelviewer2007"   &&  ( SET "Office2007=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "excel2007"         &&  ( SET "Office2007=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "word2007"          &&  ( SET "Office2007=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "infopath2007"      &&  ( SET "Office2007=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "powerpoint2007"    &&  ( SET "Office2007=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "vbe62007"          &&  ( SET "Office2007=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "graph2007"         &&  ( SET "Office2007=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "pptconv2007"       &&  ( SET "Office2007=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "xlview2007"        &&  ( SET "Office2007=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "xlconv2007"        &&  ( SET "Office2007=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "wordconv2007"      &&  ( SET "Office2007=1" & EXIT /B )

::------------------------------------------------------------------
::-- Office 2010 ---------------------------------------------------
::------------------------------------------------------------------
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "Office2010"        &&  ( SET "Office2010=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "Excel2010"         &&  ( SET "Office2010=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "infopath2010"      &&  ( SET "Office2010=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "vbe72010"          &&  ( SET "Office2010=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "ace2010"           &&  ( SET "Office2010=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "graph2010"         &&  ( SET "Office2010=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "powerpoint2010"    &&  ( SET "Office2010=1" & EXIT /B )

::------------------------------------------------------------------
::-- Windows Media Player ------------------------------------------
::------------------------------------------------------------------
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "visio2001"         &&  ( SET "Office2001=1" & SET "Architecture=x86" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "Visio2002"         &&  ( SET "Office2002=1" & SET "Architecture=x86" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "visio2003"         &&  ( SET "Office2003=1" & SET "Architecture=x86" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "visio2007"         &&  ( SET "Office2007=1" & EXIT /B )
ECHO "%~1" | FINDSTR /I "vviewer2010"       &&  ( SET "Office2010=1" & EXIT /B )
EXIT /B

:FinalCheck
IF NOT DEFINED Architecture SET "Architecture=x86x64"
EXIT /B
```

Below is the script I am working on

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
SET "Titlebar=Text File Generator"
TITLE %Titlebar%
SET "SystemType=Standard"
del /f *.CSV

ECHO/ Generating Text Files. This may take up to 10 minutes...
ECHO Architecture,KB Number, File Path, Switch, ,Windows 2000,Windows XP,Server 2003,Windows Vista,Server 2008,Windows 7,Office 2000,Office 2003,Office 2007,Office 2010, ,KB Info URL>>Masterlist.csv
FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR /S /B /A:-D ^| find /c /v ""') DO SET MaxCnt=%%I
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%I IN ('DIR /S /B /A:-D') DO CALL:Generate "%%I"
EXIT /B

:Generate
SET /A CurentCnt+=1
SETLOCAL

SET /A Percent=100*%CurentCnt%/%MaxCnt%
SET Percent=!Percent!%%
TITLE %titlebar% %CurentCnt% Of %MaxCnt% (%ProgressFormat:!Percent!% Complete)

IF /I "%~x1" NEQ ".exe" (
    IF /I "%~x1" NEQ ".msu" (
        IF /I "%~x1" NEQ ".msi" (
            IF /I "%~x1" NEQ ".msp" (
                ECHO "%~1">>SkippedFiles.csv
                EXIT /B
            )
        )
    )
)
SET "Switch=/quiet /norestart"
SET "FileName=%~n1"

:: Find KB Number
set "val=!FileName:*KB=!"
ECHO !val!|findstr /brc:"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" >nul && (
    Set "KB=KB!val:~0,7!"
) || ECHO !val!|findstr /brc:"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" >nul && (
    Set "KB=KB!val:~0,6!"
) || ECHO !val!|findstr /brc:"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" >nul && (
    Set "KB=KB!val:~0,5!"
)

::Check list of superseded patches, if superseded skip this function
FINDSTR /I "%KB%" "%~dp0\Script Dependencies\Superseded-patches.txt" 2>Nul>Nul && EXIT /B

::Echo Architecture
for %%A in ( x64 x86 ia64 amd64 x86x64 ) do (
  if "!FileName:%%A=!" neq "!FileName!" (
    if not defined Architecture (set "Architecture=%%A") else set "Architecture=Error"
  )
)

::Final Check
IF "%Office2003%"=="1" SET "Switch=/Q"
IF NOT DEFINED Architecture SET "Architecture=x86x64"

::Export
IF defined KB set "KB_EXTENSION=, ,http://support.microsoft.com/kb/%KB:~2%"
IF DEFINED WinOS ( set "Exported=1" & FOR %%A in (Windows2000 WindowsXP Server2003 Vista Windows7 Server2008 Office2000 Office2003 Office2007 Office2010) DO SET "%%A=1" )
FOR %%A in (Windows2000,WindowsXP,Server2003,Vista,Windows7,Server2008,Office2000,Office2003,Office2007,Office2010) do if defined %%A ( set "Exported=1" & ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-%%A.csv )
ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%, ,%Windows2000%,%WindowsXP%,%Server2003%,%Vista%,%Server2008%,%Windows7%,%Office2000%,%Office2003%,%Office2007%,%Office2010%%KB_EXTENSION%>>MasterList.csv
IF NOT DEFINED Exported ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>Uncategorized.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

- You have way too many unnecessary CALLs. CALL is a relatively expensive command, and your code has up to 11 CALLs for each file! I have cut it down to 1 CALL per file, and it probably could be cut to none.
- You are executing like a gazillion FINDSTR commands for each file (well, maybe a slight exageration). And the searches are really simple. It should be faster to use string search and replace to find the strings instead of FINDSTR.
- I greatly simplified and optimized the code to count the files and delete the CSV files.
- The :FindKB code seems slower than it ought to be, but I left it alone.
- I completely restructured much of the code to make it easier to maintain.

There are things that don't look right to me, but I left alone:

- I don't see how `%ProgressFormat:!Percent!%` works in your TITLE section
- You define MS but don't use it.
- You conditionally define OS, but I don't see where you use it.
- You assume many variables start out undefined. They probably should be explicitly initialized to undefined.
- Your :SwitchFix code seems flawed

  - You appear to be checking for an extension, yet you pass the name
  - It looks like a misspelling */quite* -> */quiet* ?

Here is some heavily modified code. I will be shocked if there are not several bugs - It is totally untested. But there are some good ideas there if you can get it to work.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
SET "Titlebar=Text File Generator"
TITLE %Titlebar%
SET "SystemType=Standard"

::FindMS - This is constant, only needs to be done once
::Actually I can't see where MS is used at all, so I don't think it is needed.
FOR /F "Tokens=2 Delims=/" %%A IN ("%Path%") DO SET "MS=%%A"

::FOR /F %%A IN ('DIR /B /A:-D ^|findstr "csv"') DO DEL /F %%A
::I would think DEL /F *.CSV would be better, but *CSV* matches original logic
del /f *CSV*

ECHO/ Generating Text Files. This may take up to 10 minutes...
ECHO Architecture,KB Number, File Path, Switch, ,Windows 2000,Windows XP,Server 2003,Windows Vista,Server 2008,Windows 7,Office 2000,Office 2003,Office 2007,Office 2010, ,KB Info URL>>Masterlist.csv

FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR /S /B /A:-D | find /c /v ""') DO SET /A MaxCnt=%%I
FOR /F "eol=: delims=" %%I IN ('DIR /S /B /A:-D') DO CALL :Generate "%%I" 2>Nul >Nul
EXIT /B


:Generate
SET /A CurentCnt+=1
SETLOCAL

::CALL:Progress %CurentCnt% %MaxCnt%
SET /A Percent=100*CurrentCnt/MaxCnt
SET Percent=!Percent!%%
TITLE %titlebar% %CurentCnt% Of %MaxCnt% (%ProgressFormat:!Percent!% Complete)

IF /I "%~x1" NEQ ".exe" (
    IF /I "%~x1" NEQ ".msu" (
        IF /I "%~x1" NEQ ".msi" (
            IF /I "%~x1" NEQ ".msp" (
                ECHO %1>>SkippedFiles.csv
                EXIT /B
            )
        )
    )
)

::CALL:FindKB "%~n1"
::FindKB
set "val=%~n1"
set "val=!val:*KB=!"
ECHO !val!|findstr /brc:"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" >nul && (
    Set "KB=KB!val:~0,7!"
) || ECHO !val!|findstr /brc:"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" >nul && (
    Set "KB=KB!val:~0,6!"
) || ECHO !val!|findstr /brc:"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" >nul && (
    Set "KB=KB!val:~0,5!"
)

FINDSTR /I "%KB%" "%~dp0\Script Dependencies\Superseded-patches.txt" >Nul && EXIT /B

::CALL:PathFix "%~1"
::PathFix
SET "FilePath=%~1"
SET "FilePath=!FilePath:*%~dp0=!"

::CALL:FindArchitecture "%~n1"
::FindArchitecture
set "Architecture="
set "val=%~n1"
for %%A in ( x64 x86 ia64 amd64 x86x64 ) do (
  if "!val:%%A=!" neq "!val!" (
    if not defined Architecture (set "Architecture=%%A") else set "Architecture=Error"
  )
)

::CALL:FindMS - This is a constant value so moved to front and done only once. I don't think it is needed at all

::CALL:FindOS "%~n1"
::FindOS
set "val=%~n1"
set "cmd="
for %%A in (
  "Windows2000=SET Windows2000=1"
  "WindowsXP=SET WindowsXP=1"
  "WindowsServer2003=SET Server2003=1"
  "Windows5.1=SET WindowsXP=1"
  "Windows5.2=SET Server2003=1"
  "Windows6.0=SET Vista=1"
  "Windows6.1=SET Windows7=1&SET Server2008=1"
  "Windows7=SET Windows7=1"
  "Vista=SET Vista=1"
  "Server2008=SET Server2008=1"
) do for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%B in (%%A) do if "!val:%%B=!" neq "!val!" ( 
  if not defined cmd (set "cmd=%%C") else (
    set "cmd=!cmd!&%%C"
    set "OS=Error"
  )
)
(%cmd%)

::CALL:CustomRules "%~x1"
set "val=%~x1"
if "!val:972581=!" neq "!val!" SET "KB=KB972581"
set "cmd="
for %%A in (
  "MS09-035=set WinOS=All"
  "msxml4=set WinOS=All"
  "NDP40=set WinOS=All"
  "KB890830=set WinOS=All"
  "NetFramework=set WinOS=ALL"
  "msxml6=set Server2003=1"
  "NDP20=set WindowsXP=1&set Server2003=1"
  "KB969878=set WindowsXP=1&set Server2003=1"
  "WYukon2005Setup=set Server2003=1&set Server2008=1"
  "KB952068=set Server2008=1&set Server2003=1"
  "KB954600=set Server2008=1&set Server2003=1"
  "KB924430=set Server2000=1&set Server2003=1&set Architecture=x86"
  "messenger=set Server2000=1&set Server2003=1&set WindowsXP=1&set Architecture=x86"
  "msxml4=set WinOS=All&set Architecture=x86x64"
  "KB974882=set WinOS=All&set Architecture=x86x64"
  "vcredist=set WinOS=All"
  "WindowsServer2003=set Server2003=1"
  "KB974945=set WinOS=All"
  "WindowsMedia=set WinOS=All"
  "Windows-2000-XP=set WindowsXP=1&set Server2000=1"
  "KB960089=set Server2008=1&set Server2003=1"
  "KB960083=set WinOS=All"
  "KB2657424=set Server2008=1&set Vista=1&set Server2003=1&set WindowsXP=1"
  "KB2656370=set WindowsXP=1"
  "KB2541015=set Office2003=1&set Architecture=x86"
  "NDP=set WinOS=All"
  "vcredist=set WinOS=All&set Switch=/q"
  ";----------------------------------------------------------------"
  ";--Office--------------------------------------------------------"
  ";----------------------------------------------------------------"
  "Officexp=set WindowsXP=1&set Architecture=x86"
  "office2000=set Office2000=1&set Architecture=x86"
  "Office2003=set Office2003=1&set Architecture=x86"
  "outlook2003=set Office2003=1&set Architecture=x86"
  "Project2003=set Office2003=1&set Architecture=x86"
  ";----------------------------------------------------------------"
  ";--Office2007----------------------------------------------------"
  ";----------------------------------------------------------------"
  "Office2007=set Office2007=1"
  "publisher2007=set Office2007=1"
  "access2007=set Office2007=1"
  "outlook2007=set Office2007=1"
  "excelviewer2007=set Office2007=1"
  "excel2007=set Office2007=1"
  "word2007=set Office2007=1"
  "infopath2007=set Office2007=1"
  "powerpoint2007=set Office2007=1"
  "vbe62007=set Office2007=1"
  "graph2007=set Office2007=1"
  "pptconv2007=set Office2007=1"
  "xlview2007=set Office2007=1"
  "xlconv2007=set Office2007=1"
  "wordconv2007=set Office2007=1"
  ";----------------------------------------------------------------"
  ";--Office2010----------------------------------------------------"
  ";----------------------------------------------------------------"
  "Office2010=set Office2010=1"
  "Excel2010=set Office2010=1"
  "infopath2010=set Office2010=1"
  "vbe72010=set Office2010=1"
  "ace2010=set Office2010=1"
  "graph2010=set Office2010=1"
  "powerpoint2010=set Office2010=1"
  ";----------------------------------------------------------------"
  ";--WindowsMediaPlayer--------------------------------------------"
  ";----------------------------------------------------------------"
  "visio2001=set Office2001=1&set Architecture=x86"
  "Visio2002=set Office2002=1&set Architecture=x86"
  "visio2003=set Office2003=1&set Architecture=x86"
  "visio2007=set Office2007=1"
  "vviewer2010=set Office2010=1"
) do for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%B in (%%A) do if "!val:%%B=!" neq "!val! (
  set "cmd=%%C"
  goto :CustomBreak
)
:CustomBreak
(%cmd%)

::CALL:SwitchFix "%~n1"
::SwitchFix
SET "Switch=/quite /norestart"
IF "%Office2003%"=="1" SET "Switch=/Q"
IF "%~n1"==".msu" SET "Switch=/quiet /norestart"

::CALL:FinalCheck
IF NOT DEFINED Architecture SET "Architecture=x86x64"

::CALL:Export
::Export
set "KB_EXTENSION="
if defined KB set "KB_EXTENSION=, ,http://support.microsoft.com/kb/%KB:~2%"
ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%, ,%Windows2000%,%WindowsXP%,%Server2003%,%Vista%,%Server2008%,%Windows7%,%Office2000%,%Office2003%,%Office2007%,%Office2010%%KB_EXTENSION%>>MasterList.csv
for %%A in (
  Windows2000
  WindowsXP
  Server2003
  Vista
  Windows7
  Server2008
  Office2000
  Office2003
  Office2007
  Office2010
) do if defined %%A (
  set "Exported=1"
  ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-%%A.csv
)
if defined WinOS (
  set "Exported=1"
  for %%A in (
    Windows2000
    WindowsXP
    Server2003
    Vista
    Windows7
    Server2008
  ) do ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>%SystemType%-%%A.csv
)
IF NOT DEFINED Exported ECHO %Architecture%,%KB%,%FilePath%,%Switch%>>Uncategorized.csv
EXIT /B
```

Comment: mind taking a second look at the get OS part? can't seem to get that to work correctly o.0. Also there was a missing " after !val! in that statement. Anyways if you would take a second look at that and see if you can get it to work it would be greatly appreciated! I updated my original post to show what I have gotten to work, also wanted to say many thanks for the work you put into this, i figured there had to be a way besides the retarded piped echo, but wouldn't of imagined that it would be been with the "for" command.

Comment: @user1451070 - Fixed FindOS - Besides missing quote there was a pair of `!` that didn't belong. The main change in my code besides eliminating CALLs is to replace FINDSTR with variable search and replace. The FOR/FOR /F statements are just a convenient (and efficient) way to parametize repetitive code without using CALL or GOTO.

Comment: Well I seem to have everything working thankfully, not only does it work significantly faster, the find function is a lot more reliable. For some reason piping out to a findstr method is very picky and only really works whenever it feels like it. Once I have the script tweaked to satisfaction I'll post the final source code. Thank you very much for your help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user1451070 - Don't forget to accept the answer if it meets your needs. FINDSTR can be temperamental, but once you understand the limitations it is very predictable. See [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868/1012053)